# Print the Position of Number of "1's" present in a string in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2008

I am making a program That Converts a hexa value to a binary value . well i did make it but now i am facing an issue in the 2nd part of my program which is

Now i want to display the position of "1" present in my Binary Which is made 
Like 
For example 
my binary is

> 0100100101101

it should tell me

> 2,5,8,10,11,13

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

     {
        string temp = textBox1.Text;
        string binary = ConvertTOBinary(temp);


     }                  // This is the code of my Button 

public string ConvertTOBinary(string temp)
    {

        string binaryval = "";
        binaryval = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(temp, 16), 2);
        MessageBox.Show(binaryval);
        return binaryval;
     }
```

I am making it in C# !!

Comment: Have you looked into [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx)?

Comment: loop through the string, if the character is one, print its index + 1.
or I didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: No , please can you elaborate further ?

Comment: `IndexOf` tells you the index of a searched letter, you can then search again starting 1 after the last found to find the next. I recommend you read the MSDN, write up a solution, and if no one has posted a answer how to do it post a answer showing how you implemented `IndexOf`

Answer (score 6):

```
var indexes=binary.Select((x,i)=>new{digit=x,index=i})
                  .Where(x=>x.digit=='1')
                  .Select(x=>x.index+1);
```

or in regex

```
var indexes=Regex.Matches(binary,"1")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(x=>x.Index+1);
```

or

```
List<int> indexes=new List<int>();
for(int i=0;i<binary.length;i++)
{
    if(binary[i]=='1')indexes.Add(i+1);
}
```

Comment: Too fast for me!  Just what I was thinking.

Comment: `.ToCharArray()` isn't even necessary.

Comment: @HamzaNawazDBA you need to import System.Linq;

Comment: And then to put into the string as required: `var indexesText = string.Join(",", indexes);`

Answer (score 1):

As a single select:

```
var indexes = binary
                .Select((c, index) => c == '1' ? index + 1 : 0)
                .Where(indexPlus1 => indexPlus1 > 0);
```

Then the code to put into form "2,5,8,10,11,13":

```
var indexesText = string.Join(",", indexes);
```

Comment: public string ConvertTOBinary(string temp)
        {
                    
            string binaryval = "";
            
           
 binaryval = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(temp, 16), 2);
 MessageBox.Show(binaryval);
 var indexes = binary
.Select((c, index) => c == '1' ? index + 1 : 0)
.Where(indexPlus1 => indexPlus1 > 0);
var indexesText = string.Join(",", indexes);
MessageBox.Show(indexesText);
   return binaryval;
}
This is what my code looks like now When im Running it , it says "Cannot use local variable 'binary' before it is declared"

Open in EDIT Mode to view properly,help plz

Comment: This code is not to be put in `ConvertTOBinary`. You must put my code after `string binary = ConvertTOBinary(temp);` in `button1_Click`

Comment: Or change `binary` to be `binaryval`