# Position of Indexes present in a string in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, coding-style, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Basically , i am making a program which comprizes of two portions

1) Convert the given string from HEX TO BINARY ( DID IT )

The part i am having problems is 
:-

2) Print the position of 1's present in the converted string 
For eg my converted string is

1011000001001 SO i want to print   1,3,4,10,13 ( These are position of 1's in the string )

My code is :-

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
      {

        string temp = textBox1.Text;
        string binary = ConvertTOBinary(temp);
        //Console.WriteLine(binaryval);

    }
```

public string ConvertTOBinary(string temp)
        {

```
        string binaryval = "";



        binaryval = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(temp, 16), 2);
        MessageBox.Show(binaryval);


        var indexes = binaryval
            .Select((c, index) => c == '1' ? index + 1 : 0)
            .Where(indexPlus1 => indexPlus1 > 0);
        var indexesText = string.Join(",", indexes);
        MessageBox.Show(indexes);

        return binaryval;


    }
```

I am getting errors :-

1  The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments'

2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'

3   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Documents and Settings\Hamza\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Import-Compare\Import-Compare\Parser.cs    46  13  Import-Compare
Error

4   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

Please HELP NEEDED !! :(

Comment: Please use a diffrent title than your last question, it makes it much more likely that your question will be closed for being a exact duplicate.

Comment: You might want to try slapping ToArray() on the end of all the LINQ. Or reading the manual.

Comment: Its so much related to your previous question. You already have an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19186403/961113) If there is something that is still not working then post the comment on that answer, **rather than following an incorrect answer**

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", str.Select((r, i) => new { Value = r, Index = i }).Where(r => r.Value == '1').Select(r => r.Index + 1)));`

Answer (score 0):

Linq is a wonderful thing but sometimes it's easier and more importantly clearer to do things the "ole school" way:

```
        var test = "1011000001001";
        var answer = new StringBuilder();

        var ix = test.IndexOf('1');
        while (ix > -1) {
            ix = ix + 1;
            answer.AppendFormat("{0},", ix);
            ix = test.IndexOf('1', ix);
            }
        var counts = answer.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' });
        Console.WriteLine(counts);
```

Remember one day you might have to return to that code and figure out what it does.